# getting all rows from db mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 var listdata = db.UserDetails.Select(m => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = m.userid.ToString(),
                    Text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",m.bankname,m.userid,m.gender,m.name)
                 });
```

Here `UserDetails` is the table that is present in the database and this is the way i am trying to display every entry of the table.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult getAll()
        {
             var listdata = db.UserDetails.Select(m => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = m.userid.ToString(),
                    Text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",m.bankname,m.userid,m.gender,m.name)
                 });



            return View("getAll", listdata);
        }
```

**View**

```
 @model UserApp.Models.UserDetails
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "getAll";
    }

    <h2>getAll</h2>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gender)
            </td>

        </tr>

    }
```

**Model**

```
namespace UserApp.Models
{
    public class UserModel : IEnumerable<UserModel>
    {
        public int userid {get; set;}
        public string name{get; set;}
        public IList<SelectListItem> bankname { get; set; }
        public string gender{get; set;}
    }
}
```

How do i get the elements and display them properly on the view? 
I can't seem to get a proper solution.

Stuck on this thing for hours.

P.s: new to it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are posting your listdata as a model, but your listdata is not defined as a model. No where in your code are you assigning values to your model, and the model you are calling in your view is not the same model as the model you described. Thus no data is displaying.

Comment: how would you approach towards the solution?  what would be your answer? Could you help a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add ToList() for your listdata to make it list, currently it is still [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx) , second your view accepts model, you are passing list of model, I guess you want that to be list not model, something like this

```
 @model List<UserApp.Models.UserDetails>
```

Third, you are selecting `SelectListItem` but you are using `UserApp.Models.UserDetails`, I think you should be doing something like this

```
     var listdata = db.UserDetails.ToList().Select(x => new UserApp.Models.UserDetails {
                     userid  = x.userid, (repeat the same for all)
                       }).ToList();
```

because looking at your code you don't need `selectListItem`, you need `UserApp.Models.UserDetails`.

That should fix all your problems, I hope I didn't miss any.

Comment: how do i display those results on the view part? could you please update the view part too?

Comment: What error you are getting, there is nothing more to update in your view, just the model part

Comment: everything works but i get this `The entity or complex type 'Database1Model.UserDetails' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

Comment: yes, probably because of this `public IList<SelectListItem> bankname { get; set; }`, why you are using list of select list items, bank name should be string I guess right ? Make it string and everything should be fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155770/discussion-between-botjr-and-munzer).

Comment: Why in the world would your get all `UserDetails`, convert it to a `List<UserDetails>` and then loop through them all to create another `List<UserDetails>` - its just pointless extra overhead.

Comment: I thought it is view model

Comment: @StephenMuecke what's your solution?

Comment: @BOTJr. - All you need is `var listdata = db.UserDetails.ToList();` if the view is `@model List<UserApp.Models.UserDetails>` (but I have no idea what you trying to do by creating a `class UserModel` that implements `IEnumerable<UserModel>`)

Answer (score 0):

My approach may not be the best approach but it seems to work for me.

I usually have my model for the item :

model :

```
namespace UserApp.Models
{
    public class UserModel 
    {
        public int userid {get; set;}
        public string name{get; set;}
        public IList<SelectListItem> bankname { get; set; }
        public string gender{get; set;}
    }
```

}

Then I have in my database class ( a class that calls the database and populates the queries etc: Call it CodeDB() for this example)

DB getter :

```
public List<UserModel> getUsers(){
{
List<UserModel> myUsers = new List<userModel>();
// however you are accessing your db do it here
string sql = "select * ...";
//access DB 
//open connection 
//run query command   usually for me it is  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(rdr.Read()){
    UserModel retrievedUser = new UserModel();
    retrievedUser.userid = (int)rdr[0];
    retrievedUser.name = rdr[1].ToString();
    ...  add the other fields 

    myUsers.Add(retrievedUser); 
   }
   //close db connection 
   return myUsers
}
```

In my Controller

```
//call my database class
CodeDB() DB = new CodeDB()

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult getAll()
    {

        List<UserModel> viewUsers = DB.getUsers();
        ViewBag.users = viewUsers 
        return View();
    }
```

in the view

```
 @{ 
      if(Viewbag.users != null)
      {
         foreach(UserApp.Models.UserModel u in ViewBag.users)
         {
            @Html.Raw( " userID : " + u.userid +" Gender : " + u.gender) 
         }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do. MVC Scaffolding of Crud with there Views Auto Generated
When you make your controller There's an option "MVC Controller with Views" 
Then it will ask For your Model that you want to use for scaffolding which will be 
"UserModel" Then just give your Controller a Name.
Now if you look at the Index View of your Controller it will have all the attributes you want and don't want.But of course, you can remove the unnecessary attributes 
Hope this helps!